# Programa que da promedios y se decide si es acreedor a una beca no imprime nombre

Tags: c

Estoy tratando de hacer un programa que permita capturar las calificaciones de los alumnos para obtener su promedio y determinar si es candidato a un porcentaje de beca e imprimir los resultados después de limpiar la pantalla:

```
Nombre del Alumno:
Promedio:
Porcentaje de Beca:
Materia 1: calificación_numérica
Materia 2: calificación_numérica
Materia 3: calificación_numérica
Materia 4: calificación_numérica
```

El problema que tengo es que no imprime el nombre ni los promedios de las materias.

El código que llevo hecho es el siguiente:

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

main()
{
    char opc, name, m1, m2 ,m3, m4;

    float cal1, cal2, cal3, cal4, totmat, sumcal, promedio;
    
    printf("\nEste programa indica si el alumno fue o no acreedor a una beca\n");
    printf("\n Inserte en nombre del alumno:\n");
    scanf("%s", &name);

     /* Lectura de las asignaturas*/
    printf("Ingrese el nombre y calificacion de cuatro asignaturas \n ");
        
    printf("\n Materia No. 1: ");
    scanf("%s", &m1);
    do {
        printf("\nCalifcacion materia 1 en escala del 0 al 10:\n ");
        scanf("%f", &cal1);
        if ((cal1 < 0) || (cal1 > 10))
            printf(" La calificación debe ser entre 1 y 10  \n");
    } while ((cal1 < 0)|| (cal1 > 10));

    printf("\n Materia No. 2:\n ");
    scanf("%s", &m2); 
    do {
        printf("\nCalifcacion materia 2 en escala del 0 al 10:\n ");
        scanf("%f", &cal2);
        if ((cal2 < 0) || (cal2 > 10))
            printf(" La calificacion debe ser entre 1 y 10   "); 
    } while ((cal2 < 0) || ( cal2 > 10));
    
    
    printf("\n Materia No. 3: ");
    scanf("%s", &m3); 
    do{
        printf("\nCalifcacion materia 3 en escala del 0 al 10: \n\n");
        scanf("%f", &cal3);
        if ((cal3 < 0) || (cal3 > 10))
            printf(" La calificacion debe ser entre 1 y 10   "); 
    } while ((cal3 < 0) || ( cal3 > 10));
    
    
    printf("\n Materia No. 4: ");
    scanf("%s", &m2); 
    do {
        printf("\nCalifcacion materia 2 en escala del 0 al 10: ");
        scanf("%f", &cal4);
        if ((cal2 < 0) || (cal2 > 10))
            printf(" La calificacion debe ser entre 1 y 10   "); 
    } while ((cal4 < 0) || ( cal4 > 10));
    
    totmat = 4;
    sumcal = (cal1 + cal2 + cal3 + cal4);

    promedio = (sumcal/totmat);

    system("cls");
    
    printf("\n Nombre: ");
    printf("\n\n Su promedio es de: %.2f ", promedio);
    if (promedio > 8 && promedio < 9) {
        printf("\n Felicidades tienes un 30 porciento de beca");
    }
    else if (promedio >= 9 && promedio <= 10) {
        printf ("\n Felicidades tienes un 50 porciento de beca");
    }
    else {
        printf("Su promedio no es suficiente para ser acreedor a una beca");
    }
        
    printf("\n Materia 1: %.2f", m1);
    printf("\n Materia 2: %.2f", m2);
    printf("\n Materia 3: %.2f", m3);
    printf("\n Materia 4: %.2f", m4);   
}
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Las variables `name, m1, m2 ,m3, m4` deben ser declarado como un *array* de caracteres. **Ejemplo:** `char name[50];`

Comment: Pues `printf("\n Nombre: ");` no va a imprimir nunca el contenido de la variable con el nombre porque no la estás usando.

Answer (score 2):

> > El problema que tengo es que no imprime el nombre ni los promedios de las materias.

No te imprime nada por dos razones:

**1.-** Las variables `name, m1, m2 ,m3, m4` son de tipo `char` y solo almacenan únicamente un caracter.

**2.-** Al final imprimes el nombre de la materia de esta forma:

```c
printf("\n Materia 1: %.2f", m1);
```

El especificador `%f` es para imprimir datos flotantes, lo que se necesita en este caso es el `%s`, para imprimir el nombre.

**Solución:** Para almacenar más de un caracter, se necesita de un *array* de caracteres.

**Ejemplo:**

```c
char name[20], m1[20], m2[20] , m3[20], m4[20];
```

**Algunas observaciones a tomar en cuenta:**

**1.-** Cuando pidas una cadena por teclado con `scanf`, intenta agregarle el tamaño del búfer en el especificador de formato.

**Ejemplo:**

```c
printf("\n Materia No. 1: ");
scanf("%19s", m1);
```

En este caso, la función `scanf` solo leerá hasta `19` caracteres (porque hay que dejar un espacio para el caracter nulo), por lo tanto, si intentas ingresar más de la cuenta, no ocurrirá un desbordamiento de búfer.

**2.-** La función `main` debe retornar un valor de tipo `int`.

El código completo quedaría así:

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char opc;
    char name[20], m1[20], m2[20] , m3[20], m4[20];

    float cal1, cal2, cal3, cal4, totmat, sumcal, promedio;
    
    printf("\nEste programa indica si el alumno fue o no acreedor a una beca\n");
    printf("\n Inserte en nombre del alumno:\n");
    scanf("%19s", name);

     /* Lectura de las asignaturas*/
    printf("Ingrese el nombre y calificacion de cuatro asignaturas \n ");
        
    printf("\n Materia No. 1: ");
    scanf("%19s", m1);
    do {
        printf("\nCalifcacion materia 1 en escala del 0 al 10:\n ");
        scanf("%f", &cal1);
        if ((cal1 < 0) || (cal1 > 10))
            printf(" La calificación debe ser entre 1 y 10  \n");
    } while ((cal1 < 0)|| (cal1 > 10));

    printf("\n Materia No. 2:\n ");
    scanf("%19s", m2); 
    do {
        printf("\nCalifcacion materia 2 en escala del 0 al 10:\n ");
        scanf("%f", &cal2);
        if ((cal2 < 0) || (cal2 > 10))
            printf(" La calificacion debe ser entre 1 y 10   "); 
    } while ((cal2 < 0) || ( cal2 > 10));
    
    
    printf("\n Materia No. 3: ");
    scanf("%19s", m3); 
    do{
        printf("\nCalifcacion materia 3 en escala del 0 al 10: \n\n");
        scanf("%f", &cal3);
        if ((cal3 < 0) || (cal3 > 10))
            printf(" La calificacion debe ser entre 1 y 10   "); 
    } while ((cal3 < 0) || ( cal3 > 10));
    
    
    printf("\n Materia No. 4: ");
    scanf("%19s", m4); 
    do {
        printf("\nCalifcacion materia 2 en escala del 0 al 10: ");
        scanf("%f", &cal4);
        if ((cal2 < 0) || (cal2 > 10))
            printf(" La calificacion debe ser entre 1 y 10   "); 
    } while ((cal4 < 0) || ( cal4 > 10));
    
    totmat = 4;
    sumcal = (cal1 + cal2 + cal3 + cal4);

    promedio = (sumcal/totmat);

    system("cls");
    
    printf("\n Nombre: %s ", name);
    printf("\n\n Su promedio es de: %.2f ", promedio);
    if (promedio > 8 && promedio < 9) {
        printf("\n Felicidades tienes un 30 porciento de beca");
    }
    else if (promedio >= 9 && promedio <= 10) {
        printf ("\n Felicidades tienes un 50 porciento de beca");
    }
    else {
        printf("Su promedio no es suficiente para ser acreedor a una beca");
    }
        
    printf("\n Materia 1: %s", m1);
    printf("\n Materia 2: %s", m2);
    printf("\n Materia 3: %s", m3);
    printf("\n Materia 4: %s", m4);  
    return 0;
}
```

*Sí divides el problema en subproblemas, vencerás el problema*.. Así que sí trabajas con funciones, pues el código será más fácil de leer y además de eso, evitas la redundancia de código.

**Ejemplo:**

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

void pedirCalificacion(char[], float*, int);

int main(void)
{
    char name[20], m1[20], m2[20] , m3[20], m4[20];
    float cal1, cal2, cal3, cal4, totmat, sumcal, promedio;
    
    printf("\nEste programa indica si el alumno fue o no acreedor a una beca\n");
    printf("\n Inserte en nombre del alumno:\n");
    scanf("%19s", name);
     /* Lectura de las asignaturas*/
    printf("Ingrese el nombre y calificacion de cuatro asignaturas \n ");
    pedirCalificacion(m1, &cal1, 1);
    pedirCalificacion(m2, &cal2, 2);
    pedirCalificacion(m3, &cal3, 3);
    pedirCalificacion(m4, &cal4, 4);
    
    totmat = 4;
    sumcal = (cal1 + cal2 + cal3 + cal4);

    promedio = (sumcal/totmat);

    system("cls");
    
    printf("\n Nombre: %s", name);
    printf("\n\n Su promedio es de: %.2f ", promedio);
    if (promedio > 8 && promedio < 9) 
        printf("\n Felicidades tienes un 30 porciento de beca");
    else if (promedio >= 9 && promedio <= 10) 
        printf ("\n Felicidades tienes un 50 porciento de beca");
    else 
        printf("Su promedio no es suficiente para ser acreedor a una beca");
     
    printf("\n Materia 1: %s", m1);
    printf("\n Materia 2: %s", m2);
    printf("\n Materia 3: %s", m3);
    printf("\n Materia 4: %s", m4);  
    return 0;
}

void pedirCalificacion(char m[], float* cal, int num)
{
    printf("\n Materia No. %d: ", num);
    scanf("%19s", m); 
    do 
    {
        printf("\nCalifcacion materia %d en escala del 0 al 10: ", num);
        scanf("%f", cal);
        if (*cal < 0 || *cal > 10)
            printf(" La calificacion debe ser entre 1 y 10   "); 
    } while (*cal < 0 ||  *cal > 10);
}
```

Comment: Mil gracias, es mi primer programa, acabo de iniciar la carrera y me has ayudado mucho.

Comment: @NéstorValdez Sí la respuesta resolvió tu problema, no olvides de [aceptar la respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas).